# Do limits commute in the case of "uniform convergence in a neighbourhood of infinity"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose I know that $a_{nk}$ converges pointwise to $a_k$ when $n$ goes to infinity for all $k \geq 1$ and that, furthermore, $a_{nk}$ converges to $a_n$ when $k$ goes to infinity "uniformly in $n$ in a neighbourhood of infinity", by this I mean that $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists k_0, n_0$ such that $k \geq k_0 \Rightarrow |a_{nk}-a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$. In other words, it is uniform past some index depending on $\epsilon$. If this index is constant, it guess it is known the limits commute (this is regular uniform convergence), but is it still true if e.g. $n_0(\epsilon) \rightarrow +\infty$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Is it true that $\lim\limits_{k \to +\infty} \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} a_{nk}=\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \lim\limits_{k \to +\infty} a_{nk}$ in that case? Does adding the assumption that $a_k \rightarrow a$ converges help?

Thank you.

Comment: yes. It is true. You can prove that both the sequences are Cauchy, so they converge, and the difference between the two sequences goes to zero

Comment: I cannot edit my post, but $nk$ should be $n,k$ sorry (they are two different indices). @Exodd how do you define a Cauchy sequence for a two-indices sequence?

Comment: $a_n$ and $a_k$ are the two sequences